# Show tags of custom post types in WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy

In WordPress I have a custom post type called 'places' and these posts have one "places tag" each.

What PHP code should I insert in the sidebar to print the tag of the current post?

Answer (score 0):

```
global $post;

$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID);

foreach($terms as $term) {

    echo $term_single->name;
}
```

Comment: Please, always add an explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [get_the_term_list()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) function, which **returns an HTML string of taxonomy terms** associated with a post and given taxonomy. Terms are linked to their respective term listing pages.

**You can use it this way:**

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'people', 'People: ', ', ' ); ?>
```

**On page you will**

```
People: <a href="person1">Person 1</a>, <a href="person2">Person 2</a>, ...
```